# (C Programming) User name and Password Identification

Tags: c

Why do I get `format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*'`? How should I fix the problem?

Here are my codes:

```
char UserName[] = "iluvcake";
scanf("%s", &UserName);
printf("Please enter your password: \n");
char PassWord[] = "Chocolate";
scanf("%s", &PassWord);
    //if...else statement to test if the input is the correct username. 
    if (UserName == "iluvcake") 
    {
     if (PassWord == "Chocolate"){
     printf("Welcome!\n");
    }
    }else
    {
     printf("The user name or password you entered is invalid.\n");
    }
```

Comment: Because name of an array is also an address. Do `scanf("%s", UserName);` instead of `scanf("%s", &UserName);`

Comment: I know this is not your question, but I simply cannot resist. Dealing with passwords you should always: Turn echo off so the password is not shown during typing, erase the password from memory as soon as you don't need it anymore (overwrite it with 0's) and not hardcode it into your code (use hashes instead). If you put the password into the code it is nealry like putting it into a textfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. scanf for %s takes a char array/pointer, not pointer to it. drop the `&` from the `scanf` statements.
2. You cannot compare strings with `==`. Use `strcmp`.

Answer (score 4):

&UserName is a pointer to an array of char (i.e., a char**). You should use

```
scanf( "%s", UserName );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

main(){
char name[20];
char password[10];
printf("Enter username: ");
scanf("%s",name);
printf("Enter password: ");
scanf("%s",password);
if (strcmp(name, "Admin") == 0 && strcmp(password, "pass") == 0)
printf("Access granted\n");
else printf("Access denied\n");


getch();
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Must be

```
scanf("%s", UserName);
scanf("%s", PassWord);
```

because `UserName` and `PassWord` are pointers to `char` arrays.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int serial;
int code;

printf("Type the Serial Here: ");
scanf("%d", &serial);

if(serial== 1590){
    printf("Almost there, now type the code: ");
    scanf("%d", &code);
    if(code==2359)
    {
            printf("\nYOU ARE DONE, ENJOY");
    }
    else{
            printf("TRY AGAIN NEXT TIME");
    }


}
    else{
        printf("OPPS");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OP's problem is about reading (and comparing) strings not integers.